# Return react 16 array elements in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I want to use the new react 16 feature to return array elements in my `render` but i'm getting the typescript error `Property 'type' is missing in type 'Element[]'`

```
const Elements: StatelessComponent<{}> = () => ([
  <div key="a"></div>,
  <div key="b"></div>
]);
```

What am i missing? Using **@types/react 16.0.10** and **typescript 2.5.3**

Comment: it's still a fresh version and the typings are not quite ready. Here you have a link where you can follow progress: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/19363 (they merged it a few days ago but people are still having issues)

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked the latest typings and they forgot to add new definitions in a stateless component interface. I've raised the issue and it should be fixed soon.

Returning an array from class components works so if you really need it right now you can transform your functional component to class component.

```
class Elements extends React.Component<{}> {

  render() {
    return [
       <div key="a"></div>,
       <div key="b"></div>
    ]

  }
}
```

or temporarily extend React typings using module augmentation. Just put the following code somewhere in one of your .ts files and typescript will automatically detect changes in definitions.

```
declare module "react" {
  interface StatelessComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P & { children?: ReactNode }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>[] | ReactElement<any> | null;
    propTypes?: ValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Is there a link to the issue? Still not fixed =\ Thanks. Want to bump it up a little

Comment: This is the most recent discussion about this problem I can find: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20356

Comment: There is a PR in Typescript repo that's waiting for merge. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20239

Comment: Looks like there's a more recent PR now—but it's still not resolved: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699

Comment: I think that refactoring to class component is not solving the case. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017454/jsx-element-type-element-is-not-a-constructor-function-for-jsx-elements/54903788#54903788

Comment: this still is happening

Answer (score 7):

Or use [React fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
render() {
    return 
       <>
        <div key="a"></div>,
        <div key="b"></div>
       </>
}
```

Comment: Good call! This is so much cleaner.

Comment: React expects to return an object instead of an array, so this is a solid approach