# JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

> "@types/react": "^16.7.17"
>   "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11"
>   "typescript": "^3.2.2"

```js
function ArryElement() {
  return [
    <div key='1'>1</div>,
    <div key='2'>2</div>
  ];
}

function App() {
  return <ArryElement />
}
```

Comment: It seems typescript does not allow you to return an array of elements from `render`. Simply use `React.Fragment` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return react 16 array elements in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643517/return-react-16-array-elements-in-typescript)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is because React is expecting to return an object. What you do in this example, is return an array instead.

As a user mentioned above, wrapping it in a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (which is an object) will solve the case